# A couple questions regarding Calculus on Manifolds Theorem 3-11

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, proof-explanation

I'm struggling to unuderstand a couple of steps in a proof of a theorem (**3-11**) in Spivak's *Calculus in Manifolds*. Below I post the relevant sections of the proof and afterwards my doubts.

---

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

$$\textbf{First question: Why is the sum in } \textit{Case 2} \textbf{ finite?}$$

If $x\in A_i$, then $x\notin B_j$ for $j\ge i+2$. Beyond that, I do not understand the reasoning.

$$\textbf{Second question: Why is } \{x\in A : d(x,\partial A) \ge 1/i\} \textbf{ a closed set (in } \textit{Case 3 } \textbf{) ?}$$
Proving so is necessary to show each $A_i$ is compact. I believe the distance between a point $x$ and a set $S$ is defined as
$$d(x,S):= \sup\{d(x,s):s\in S\}.$$

Answer (score 1):

1. For first question : 
   if $x\notin B_j$ for $j \geq i+1$, then the summation on all $ \varphi \in \Phi_k$ for all $k$ , is just summation for $k \leq i+1$ :
   $$
   \sigma(x) = \sum_{\varphi \in \Phi_i \, (all \,i)} \varphi(x) = \sum_{\varphi \in \Phi_1} \varphi(x)+\sum_{\varphi \in \Phi_2} \varphi(x) + \dots +\sum_{\varphi \in \Phi_{i+1}} \varphi(x).
   $$
   $\Phi_i$ is partition of unity for **compact** set $B_i$ which was the case *1*. so each one of these summations are finite. therefore it's finite summation over finite summations!
2. you're talking about wrong set, the condition $|x|<i$ is necessary for these sets to be compact!
   $d(.,F): E \subset \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{> 0}$ is a Lipchitz continues function. (for some $E,F \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ which $E \cap F = \emptyset$) and $[\frac{1}{i},M]$ is a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}_{>0}$ so
   $$
   A_i := \{x \in A | \, |x|<i \quad, d(x,\partial A)\geq \frac{1}{i} \}
   $$
   is preimage of this function for $[\frac{1}{i},M]$ (for $F=\partial A$ and $E=\{x \in A | |x|<i \}$ which is open so $\partial A \cap E = \emptyset$). hence $A_i$ is compact subset of induced topology on $A$. (knowing $\mathbb{R}^n$ is Hausdorff)
   $M$ comes from compactness of $C_i = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n | |x|<i \}$. since it's compact, the $d(C_i,F)$ is bounded.